# CreateWindowEx returns null : unable to create a window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

CreateWindowEx method always returns null.

I don't know whats wrong, but I am not able to even create a window.

My window procedure is a static method, BaseWndApplication::WndProc, defined in another class, I am not sure if that should cause any problems, As I can register my WNDCLASSEX structure successfully.

Please heeeelp!!

```
int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine ,
    int nCmdShow
    )
{

const char * WINDOW_CLASS_NAME = "D2DAppClass";
HRESULT hr;
{
    // Register the window class.
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = BaseWndApplication::WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.lpszClassName = WINDOW_CLASS_NAME;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return E_FAIL;

    HWND m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        WINDOW_CLASS_NAME,
        "Direct2D Demo App",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        static_cast<UINT>(ceil(640.f)),
        static_cast<UINT>(ceil(480.f)),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    hr = m_hWnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` have to say about that?  You might want to refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for common failure reasons.

Comment: it returns error code 0, which i think is "operation completed successflly"

Comment: What is the purpose of `static_cast<UINT>(ceil(640.f))`?  Why not just `640`?  Your code with a stub WndProc and without the `ceil` nonsense works fine for me.

Comment: That is just copied from MSDN site as is, its not causing any problem.

Comment: I just called GetProcessId(hInstance) and GetLastError says that the handle is invalid.

Comment: okay i found the issue, thanks a lot for your help Retired Ninja

Comment: The main lesson to learn from this is to include a complete program that reproduces the problem. You did not do this. Had you done so you would have had an immediate answer. In fact, making a small repro program would probably have led to you finding the problem yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a problem with my callback method. It was set to return 0;

I changed it as follows, and then it worked:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: In particular returning `0`/`FALSE` for the [`WM_NCCREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632635.aspx) message will terminate window creation, which will eventually have the `CreateWindow[Ex]` call return a `NULL` handle. No error is recorded either, since nothing really failed.

Comment: I'm not sure why people were down voting the question, I was running into the exact same problem and because I am just learning C++ I was having trouble finding the solution to the same problem.  Your answer was exactly the fix I needed, and @IInspectable explained the why.  Now I am a little better for it! Thank you

Comment: @AaronMurray: The question was voted down, because the OP refused to provide the requested information. Since the issue is caused by a bug in the window procedure, that window procedure needs to be included in the question.

Comment: revolutionary: Yes already upvoted the question and the answer.

@IInspectable I am not seeing where he refused to provide any requested information but I appreciate your comment as to why it wasn't working, thank you!

Comment: @AaronMurray: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154322/createwindowex-returns-null-unable-to-create-a-window/26154752?noredirect=1#comment41006072_26154322) was asking for a complete program. It was posted after the final edit to the question, and the question still doesn't contain the relevant code for the custom window procedure. I didn't vote on the question, but that is likely the reason, why others have.